# how to send a pdf or ms excel/word file while it's open?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, pdf

Upon viewing a pdf, ms excel/word file, i often want to send to my colleague for viewing, and after sending, i will still need to keep it open to use it further. While each time I have to close it and find the folder containing this doc and then open the folder and drag it to the dialogue box, is there a convenient way to do this?

Comment: You could File Save As and send a copy to your colleague ...

Answer (score 0):

Since Word 2007, there is an extra menu item saying "E-Mail". Just click the upper left corner of the window, select "Send" and then "E-Mail", a copy of the document will be inserted as attachment of a new E-Mail-Window from Outlook.

Although this menu item must be existing since Office 2000, I don't have a running environment to check that.

Comment: bad new is that i don't use outlook on my pc, is there an alternative?

Comment: It depends on which E-Mail programm you are using. If it have an interface for Visual-Basic, it may be possible to create a VBA-Marco within Word/Excel to send the mail.

Comment: in fact i need to send to instant messenger chatbox, such as msn, skype or qq, so email isn't that necessary.